# How to filter and modify an array of objects with a single line of code?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have the following array of objects coming from my database:

```
dataFromDB = [
  { src: 'stringWithSource1',
    selected: true
  },
  { src: 'stringWithSource2',
    selected: false
  },
  { src: 'stringWithSource3',
    selected: true
  },
  AND SO ON...
];
```

When I fetch it from the database I need to store on client-side in a `state` that **must be an array of strings**, containing **only the `src` property of the objects that are `selected: true`.**

**Example:**

```
myState = [
  'stringWithSource1',
  'stringWithSource3',
  AND SO ON...
]
```

**QUESTION**

The line where I'm assigning this, is like the following (see code below):

I tried but that doesn't work because I'm keeping the unselected `src` as `null` instead of just skipping them.

```
setProductDetails({
  // ... other properties,
  images: dataFromDB.images.map((item) => {
    return item.selected ? item.src : null;
  }
});
```

How can I achieve this behavior in a single line like this? I know I could create an auxiliar variable and handle this. But I would like a one-liner in this case. Is this possible? It feels like I should filter and map at the same time?

Comment: _" in a single line"_ - Why? Make it as detailed as necessary that you or whoever is reading the code immediately understand what is happening here.

Comment: Because I'm doing this inside a `setState()`. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need two parts, because the filtering does not map a value, but the original items.

You could filter by `selected` and then map `src`.

```
images: dataFromDB.images
    .filter(({ selected }) => selected)
    .map(({ src }) => src)
```